# how to get even odd ids in different columns on single query?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example I have a table like given below .. I want to have separate columns on the basis of even/odd ids

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| ID  |  Names
-----------------------------------------------------
| 1   |  Name1
-----------------------------------------------------
| 2   |  Name2
-----------------------------------------------------
| 3   |  Name3
-----------------------------------------------------
| 4   |  Name4
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I want to design a query that could give me

```
-------------------
| Even  |  Odd    |
-------------------
| Name2 |  Name1  |
-------------------
| Name4 |  Name3  |
-------------------
```

Comment: Had a nice answer for SQL SERVER using PIVOT, and then saw this was mySQL... Anyway, if you'd like to see it the SQL Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9ffac/1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select 
  max(case id%2 when 1 then name end) as odd,
  max(case id%2 when 0 then name end) as even
from your_table
group by floor((id+1)/2)
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3b0f/4)</kbd>

Comment: Nice and neat solution. Any reason you used _group by floor((id+1)/2)_ rather than _group by CEIL((id)/2)_ ?

Answer (score 2):

If your Id column contain sequential number without any gap between number then :

```
SELECT t1.name as ODD,
       t2.name as EVEN
FROM   YourTable t1
       left outer JOIN YourTable t2
         ON t1.Id + 1 = t2.Id
where t1.Id%2 = 0
```

Note : if there are gaps between number then some of the `ODD` will be shown as `NULL` or it may skip that `name` if it has gap of more than 3.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get odd or even, use next queries:
**Select for odd records:**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID % 2 = 1
```

**Select, for even**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID % 2 = 0
```

And **if you want to decorate as two columns**, try next solution:

```
SELECT
    odd.name as Odd,
    (SELECT name FROM table WHERE ID = odd.ID + 1 ) as Even
FROM
    table as odd
WHERE
    odd.ID % 2 = 1
```

Comment: these are two different queries .. i want to design which can give them to me in different column of the same query

Answer (score 0):

Find the parity (property of even or odd) using modulo operator %.

...where id%2 equals 0;

This will give you even id in result.

The ones which are not equal to 0 are the odd id.

Answer (score 0):

The above result set can be achieved by the following code -

```
SELECT Even, Odd   
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Even) AS ROW   
    FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN ID % 2 = 0 THEN Names ELSE NULL END AS 'Even'  
    FROM TableName)TAB1  
    WHERE Even IS NOT NULL)T1  
FULL OUTER JOIN   
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Odd) AS ROW  FROM  
    (SELECT CASE WHEN ID % 2 = 1 THEN Names ELSE NULL END AS 'Odd'  
    FROM TableName) TAB2  
    WHERE Odd IS NOT NULL) T2  
ON T1.ROW=T2.ROW
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ID is sequential then

```
SELECT tb1.ODD, tb2.EVEN
FROM
(
    SELECT Id, name ODD
    FROM YourTable
    where (`Id` % 2) = 1
 ) AS tb1 

 JOIN 

 (SELECT Id, name EVEN
  FROM  YourTable
  WHERE (`Id` % 2) = 0
 ) AS tb2 

ON (tb1.Id + 1 = tb2.Id)

WHERE tb1.ODD IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY tb1.Id
```